# Parse saveAll always failed

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to query all of the object in some table and save it into new table. It's basically a tournament score and I have to backup it in the new table.

But whenever I call saveAll it's always failed. Anyone have an idea about this?

```
        var WeeklyScore =   Parse.Object.extend("WT_Forest");
        var query       =   new Parse.Query(WeeklyScore);

        query.find
        (
            function(queryResult)
            {
                var parseObjects    =   [];

                for(var i = 0; i < queryResult.length; i++)
                {
                    var BackupScore =   Parse.Object.extend("WT_Forest - Week " + ( differentDay / 7)); 
                    var backupScore =   new BackupScore();

                    backupScore.set("exp",      queryResult[i].exp);
                    backupScore.set("heroData", queryResult[i].heroData);
                    backupScore.set("isGuest",  queryResult[i].isGuest);
                    backupScore.set("name",     queryResult[i].name);
                    backupScore.set("playerID", queryResult[i].playerID);
                    backupScore.set("score",    queryResult[i].score);
                    backupScore.set("teamData", queryResult[i].teamData);

                    parseObjects.push(backupScore);
                }

                Parse.Object.saveAll(parseObjects).then
                (
                    function(savedResult)
                    {
                        response.success("Success");
                    },
                    function(errorMessage)
                    {
                        response.error("Failed " + errorMessage);
                    }
                );
            },
            function(errorMessage)
            {
                response.error(errorMessage);
            }
        );
```

Here's the response message that I received:

> Script Error: 'Failed [object Object]'

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that the problem is the Table name.
I cannot use ' ' and '-' inside the table name.
Also I have to use JSON.stringify() to read the error message.